# Ace editor multiple cursors

Tags: ace-editor

In the example below, the split button should remove all semicolons and create a new editor with the following text until the next semicolon.

However, there is an odd bug where all editors except the first one have the cursor flashing at the end of the line, but only the last field has actually got the cursor (e.g. typing after pressing split will put text in the last field). How do I prevent this?

```js
$(function() {
  function aceinit() {
    var e = ace.edit(this),
      t = $(this);
    e.setTheme("ace/theme/sqlserver");
    e.setOptions({
      maxLines: Infinity,
      highlightActiveLine: false,
      tabSize: 8,
      useSoftTabs: false,
      fixedWidthGutter: true
    });
    e.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");
    e.getSession().on('change', function() {
      $('.output').css('opacity', '0.3');
      $('.markdown-toggle').hide();
    });
    e.commands.bindKey("Tab", null);
    e.commands.bindKey("Shift-Tab", null);
    e.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(true);
    return e;
  }
  $('.ace').each(function() {
    aceinit.call(this);
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.plus', function() {
    $('main').children().slice(0, 3).clone().insertBefore($(this));
    $('.ace').each(function() {
      aceinit.call(this);
    });
    var b = $(this).prev().prev('.batch');
    var e = aceinit.call(b.find('.ace').get(0));
    e.setValue("");
    e.resize();
    e.focus();
    b.find('.results').html('');
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.split', function() {
    var b = $(this).prev('.batch');
    e = ace.edit(b.find('.ace').get(0));
    s = ';';
    b.find('.results').html('');
    setTimeout(function() {
      var split = e.getValue().split((new RegExp(s, 'im')));
      $.each(split, function(i, v) {
        if (v.trim()) {
          if (i > 0) {
            if (!b.find('.ace').filter(function() {
                return ace.edit(this).getValue() === '';
              }).length) {
              b.next().next('.plus').click();
            }
            b = b.nextAll().eq(2);
            e = ace.edit(b.find('.ace').get(0));
          }
          e.setValue(split[i].replace(/\s+$/, '').replace(/^\s+/, ''), 1);
        }
      });
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.batch {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.query.ace {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dbfiddle.uk/ace/ace.js"></script>
<main>
  <a href="#" class="plus" onclick="return false;" style="display: block;">add batch</a>
  <div class="batch" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="ace query">text1
; 
text2
; 
text3
; 
text4
; 
text5
;</div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="split" onclick="return false;" style="display: block;">split</a>
  <a href="#" class="plus" onclick="return false;" style="display: block;">add batch</a>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you are calling

```
e.focus();
```

after creating each editor, call it only for the one which you want to be focused.